# Switch the last two fields with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm looking for a way to switch the last two fields of a tab-separated file. The number of fields vary among rows, so I can't specify the field number.

Most of what I could find online was field-specific scripts. E.g. [swap two columns with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815082/swap-two-columns-with-awk)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" 'NF>1 {t=$(NF-1); $(NF-1)=$NF; $NF=t} {print}' file
```

Do a standard swap between `$NF` and `$(NF-1)` only when we have at least 2 fields. It's fatal error to access field -1 (in case of empty line, `NF==0`).

See also: [GNU awk fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'join( "\t", .words[0..*-3], .words[*-1] // "", .words[*-2] // "").trim-leading.put ;'
```

Basically, the code above creates a list of whitespace-separated elements (`words`) in the desired order (last two elements switched). The elements are `join`ed with `\t` tab, any leading whitespace is trimmed away with `trim-leading`, and the result is out`put`. This code works on tab-separated columns as well as on space-separated columns.

Note, Raku's `//` defined-OR operator is used to avoid issues with `Nil` values in String context--an `""` empty string is 'inserted' where necessary.

Sample Input (first line is blank):

```
A
A   B
A   B   C
A   B   C   D
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E   F
```

Sample Output (last two elements on each line are swapped--first line is still blank):

```
A   
B   A
A   C   B
A   B   D   C
A   B   C   E   D
A   B   C   D   F   E
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/words
https://docs.raku.org/routine/join
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the built-in variable `NF` to refer to the last field to print it before the second last field (`NF-1`):

```
awk 'NF <= 1; NF > 1 {for (i = 1; i <= NF-2; i++) printf "%s\t", $i; print $NF"\t"$(NF-1)}' file.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

One way can be :

```bsh
awk -F '\t' '
BEGIN {OFS=FS}
f=(NF>1){
  p = length-length($(NF-1)"x"$NF)
  print substr($0,1,p) $NF, $(NF-1)
}!f' file
```